# Water flow reduced after a few seconds in 2nd floor bathroom sink, cold side

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, faucet, sink

If you turn the cold water on full blast, it flows for 2-3 seconds at full, then drops off to a trickle thereafter. The hot side does not have the same issue. This began happening a few months ago, with no other issues, or changes to the plumbing.

What could be the issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Was this a sudden change or have you noticed this gradually over time? Are you in a cold climate?

Comment: What type of plumbing do you have (copper,  plastic, galvanized,  etc.)?

Answer (score 3):

A nearly-full-clogged cold water pipe. Pressure builds in time after the clog (giving the initial full blast) but it cannot sustain the flow (dropping to a trickle).